# Inserir dados do objeto pela API no Banco de dados

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, node.js, api

Recebo um objeto com os dados do front, e na api ta assim o middleware:

```
let no = require('../controllers/InsertNo')

let insertNo = (req, res, next) => {

    dados = []

    dados = req.body || ''
```

Quando dou um console.log no dados ele ta assim:

```
    { dados:
   [ [ 'ARMARIO MULTIUSO NOTAVEL URUGUAI ./BR                       ',
       '14196001       ',
       '01',
       'HOTEL LIVRAMENTO LTDA                   ',
       '051578',
       '20190108',
       '12:58',
       '27' ] ] }
{ dados:
   [ [ 'BALCAO NOTAVEL CLASSIC ./BR                                 ',
       '13588001       ',
       '02',
       'HOTEL LIVRAMENTO LTDA                   ',
       '051578',
       '20190108',
       '12:58',
       '27' ] ] }
```

Aí preciso enviar esses dados pra o Banco de dados, só que estou me perdendo no momento que envio:

```
let no = require('../controllers/InsertNo')

let insertNo = (req, res, next) => {

    dados = []

    dados = req.body || ''

  no.insertNo(dados.numos.numos, dados.cod_prod.cod_prod, dados.obs_retorno.obs_retorno, dados.data.data, dados.hora.hora, dados.cod_tec.cod_tec, dados.retorno_mont.retorno_mont, dados.item.item, (result) => {
        if (result) {
            let dados = {
                numos: result.numos,
                cod_prod: result.cod_prod,
                data: result.data,
                hora: result.hora,
                cod_tec: result.cod_tec,
                item: result.item
            }
            res.json(dados)
        } else {
            res.json({
                success: false
            })
        }
    })
```

E no controller ta assim:

```
 let sequelize = require('../../config/sequelize')


let insertNo = (NUMOS,COD_PRODUTO,OBS_RETORNO,DATA_RETORNO,HORA_RETORNO,COD_TEC,OCORRENCIA, ITEM, callback) =>{
    sequelize.query(`INSERT INTO RetornoMontagem (NUMOS,COD_PRODUTO, FILIAL, OBS_RETORNO, OBS_NOVA_OS, D_E_L_E_T, DATA_RETORNO, HORA_RETORNO,COD_TEC, OCORRENCIA, ITEM)
    VALUES ('${NUMOS}','${COD_PRODUTO}','99', '${OBS_RETORNO}', '','','${DATA_RETORNO}','${HORA_RETORNO}','000000000000'+'${COD_TEC}', '${OCORRENCIA}', '${ITEM}');`)
    .spread((result,metadata)=>{
        if (result) {
            callback(result)
        } else {
            callback({success:false})
        }
    })
}

module.exports = { insertNo }
```

Como consigo enviar esses dados do objeto para o Banco de dados?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo Angular enviei assim:

```
  InsertAPi(dados){
    return this.http.post(`${API}/insertNo`, { dados })
  }
```

e na API fiz assim:

```
let insertNo = (req, res, next) => {

    dados = []

    dados = req.body || ''
    let ok = dados.dados

    ok.forEach(e => {
        no.insertNo(e.NUMOS, e.COD_PROD, e.OBS_RETORNO, e.DATA, e.HORA, e.COD_TEC, e.RETORNO_MONT, e.ITEM, (result) => {
            if (result) {
                let dados = {
                    resp: 'SUCCESS'
                }                
            } else {
                res.json({
                    success: false
                })
            }
        })
    })
```